# Adwords Conversion Tracking in PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, google-ads-api

I have a html page with contact form. If someone fills the form, they see the "Thanks" message on the same page. HTML code for the page is

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="demo">

                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <div class="span6">
                                            <input type="text" required placeholder="First Name" name="Firstname" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="span6">
                                            <input type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" name="Lastname" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <div class="span6">
                                            <input type="email" required placeholder=" * Email" name="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="span6">
                                            <input type="text" required placeholder="Country" name="Country" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <div class="span6">
                                            <textarea name="comment" required placeholder="comment" size="100%"></textarea>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row4">
                                        <input type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn button animated bounceIn" value="request information">
                                    </div>      

                                </form>
```

and the php code is

```
if ($Email=="") {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>
            <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Please enter your email.
        </div>

    ";
}   
elseif ($firstName=="" or $lastName=="" or $country=="") {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>
            <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill all the fields.
        </div>";
}   
else{
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $_REQUEST[Email]");
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
            <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
            <strong>Thank you for your message!</strong>

        </div>

    ";  
}
```

Now I would like to integrate Google Adwords conversion code with the contact form. Could someone please assist me on this? Here is my conversion code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 955016975;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "_3SsCJzniVwQj86xxwM";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/955016975/?label=_3SsCJzniVwQj86xxwM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: put it in your last else statement, with the success message.  What isn't working?  I assume you're picking up your values before the php you posted?  You don't say what the problem is.